# rc.local - running a Bash Script with a specified user

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

im currently use this script to load my bash script as "ts3" user in crontab.

```
@reboot /home/ts3/./Advertisment.sh && /home/ts3/./ts3server_startscript.sh start inifile=ts3server.ini
```

---

Its working without problems on startup.
But i want to have it in **/etc/rc.local**

I tried:

```
sleep 10

cd /home/ts3/ && su ts3 ./Advertisment.sh

sleep 10

cd /home/ts3/ && su ts3 ./ts3server_startscript.sh start inifile=ts3server.ini
```

with no success. The Script doesnt run on startup.

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if simplifying by removing the extra steps would help?

```
sleep 10
su - ts3 -c /home/ts3/Advertisment.sh
sleep 10
su - ts3 -c /home/ts3/ts3server_startscript.sh start inifile=ts3server.ini
```

Oops, I did the syntax of the `su` command wrong.

Comment: I didn't have the syntax correct, I fixed it.  One other question...are your scripts dependent on running at a certain run-level?  Namely, do they need X to be running (RL 5)?  rc.local is executed at RL3, I believe.

Comment: still no luck. do you guys think, a init.d script would fix that?